# Explanation of Linux/Udev Audio Device Naming

Tags: kernel, audio, udev, alsa

Given the following code:

```c
  struct udev *udev_obj = udev_new();
  struct udev_enumerate *udev_enum = udev_enumerate_new(udev_obj);
  udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(udev_enum, "sound");
  udev_enumerate_scan_devices(udev_enum);

  struct udev_list_entry *udev_entries = udev_enumerate_get_list_entry(udev_enum);
  struct udev_list_entry *udev_entry = NULL;
  udev_list_entry_foreach(udev_entry, udev_entries) {
    printf("%s\n", udev_list_entry_get_name(udev_entry));
  }
```

My ThinkPad X1 Carbon with no external sound peripherals outputs:

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/hwC0D0
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/hwC0D2
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/pcmC0D0c
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/pcmC0D0p
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/pcmC0D10p
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/pcmC0D3p
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/pcmC0D7p
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/pcmC0D8p
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/pcmC0D9p
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/controlC0
/sys/devices/virtual/sound/seq
/sys/devices/virtual/sound/timer
```

I understand that C0 = card 0, D0 = device 0, and c = capture/p = playback. However:

1. What is the difference between *card0/hw/pcm/control/seq/timer*?
2. Why is there so many odd combinations, e.g card 0, device 3 and then card 0, device 7, etc. It does not seem to logically increment by one
3. What is the parent device here and how would I obtain it with `libudev`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.)

- `card0` is a single sound card, motherboard-integrated sound chip or e.g. USB sound device, that may have a number of inputs and outputs.
- `hw` virtual files are for *hardware dependent* items; basically if a sound chip or a specific part of it has some extra features that are not covered by the standard ALSA interface, those will most likely be accessible through these virtual files.
- `pcm` virtual files are the actual input and output channels of sound data.
- `control` channel is for volume settings and similar "standard" sound card controls.
- `seq` is used if you have a sound card that has MIDI sequencer functionality, or MIDI interfaces for external MIDI instruments, or a software synthesizer like `timidity` that can interface with ALSA.
- and `timer` is important when you are scheduling a number of different sounds to play in harmony, and in many other things involved with sound. So ALSA provides a timer interface that's optimized for audio-related purposes.

2.)
Only the person or team that designed the motherboard of the computer will know that for sure. But a modern HD-Audio compliant audio chip can have a large number of inputs and outputs, configurable by system firmware; perhaps the motherboard designer just picked the inputs/outputs that were physically easiest to wire to where each signal needed to go (e.g. on the correct side of the sound chip, or something).

Note that your system has just one sound input channel (the laptop's internal microphone(s)), but several outputs: one is the internal speakers/headphone output, but the others are probably providing sound to the HDMI output and/or for the DisplayPort alternate modes of any USB Type-C ports: and since DisplayPort can allow daisy-chaining of displays, there may be two or more sound output channels for each USB Type-C port.

3.)
In your case, `card0` is the parent device in ALSA sense, and `0000:00:1f.3` is its PCI(e) bus ID. This part of your question is not very clear: what exactly are you trying to do with `libudev`?

Depending on what you wish to do, something like `udevadm info -q all -a -p /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/pcmC0D0p` might give you an idea of the relationships between the components.
That particular bus ID is typical to Intel chipset-integrated HD Audio sound chips.

Comment: Thanks! In regards to point 3, I'm trying to get information from a udev sound subsystem device to be used with alsa `snd_pcm_open`. From my research, it seems best to use udev for hotplugging sound devices and alsa for retrieving information about the device, i.e. udev just triggers an alsa rescan of audio devices. I was hoping for something like udev input subsystem devices where you can inspect relevant attributes to get information about them with udev. udev sound devices seem to have little useful attributes